# Access Angular $scope in plain javascript

Tags: angularjs

I have a Controller which has something like this...

```
angular.module('kZoneApp').controller('DemandController', ['$http', '$scope', '$rootScope', 'dataFactory', '$window', '$routeParams','$sce', function ($http, $scope,$rootScope, dataFactory, $window, $routeParams,$sce) {

    $scope.channel = $routeParams.channel;
```

now within my page.html, I want to do the following....

```
<script>
 YoutubeVideoPlayer.openVideo('{{channel}}');
</script>
```

please note, I am using **Routes**, and page.html is loaded into my **ng-view** Via a Route.

```
<div id="myView" class="reveal-animation" ng-view></div>
```

I tried below code, but it returns undefined....

```
$().ready(function () {
   var  channel = angular.element("#myView").scope().channel            
   YoutubeVideoPlayer.openVideo(channel);
})
```

How can I get the value of Channel within my Template View?

**Update**

below works...but I am sure there has to be a cleaner solution

```
    setTimeout(function () {
        alert(angular.element("#myView").scope().channel)
    }, 500);
```

Comment: try change it to var  channel = angular.element(document.getElementById("myView")).scope().channel

Comment: You should do it the other way round, make `YoutubeVideoPlayer` a constant in Angular. `anuglar.module('someModule').constant('YouTube', YoutubeVideoPlayer)` then access in a directive.

Comment: same result. see my update

Comment: Callum, could you please write a quick example?

Comment: Sure give me a minute

Comment: Could you link the code to the library you're using (YoutubeVideoPlayer)

Comment: its a cordova plugin, all I can do is call the above youtube script and pass video ID to it.

Comment: how does it bind to a HTML element?

Comment: within my controller, i am getting video ID using "$routeParams.channel", which I am setting to a $scope.channel (as you can see in my code above). All I want to do is pass this scope "channel" variable to the Plain Javascript code.

Comment: [plnkr example](http://plnkr.co/edit/GyFoi3d1kn49bl8ieI7f?p=preview)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A workaround solution should be creating a variable before your Angular.module definition.

```
var scopeInAngular = null;
```

and inside controller assign controller to your variable.

```
scopeInAngular = $scope;
```

then if you manipulate anything inside angular view use

```
scopeInAngular.$apply();
```

Comment: This worked. But still had to be placed within the setTimeout command.